# fs.readdirSync alternative for my Web-App

Tags: angular, typescript, fs

I have a big problem and I hope someone can help me.
Some time ago I created a "Desktop App" with Electron, consequently, I was able to freely use the "file-system" library but now I need to transform this Electron App into a sort of WebApp that will run on a server; I've been able to convert pretty much everything, I just don't know how to bang my head to find alternatives to the "fs.readdirSync" and "fs.writeFileSync" functions. Some advice?

Here are some examples of code that use these two functions :

```
let layers = fs.readdirSync(this.invoicesDirectory.path, { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter(entry => entry.isDirectory())
    .map(entry => entry.name);;

let itemNames = fs.readdirSync(this.invoicesDirectory.path + "/" + invoicesName + "/" + itemFolderName, { withFileTypes: true })
        .filter(entry => !entry.isDirectory())
        .filter(entry => !!entry.name.match(/.*(gif|jpe?g|tiff?|png|webp|bmp)$/i))
        .map(entry => entry.name);

this.fs.writeFileSync(\${selectedDirectory[0]}/${file}`, JSON.stringify(data))`


this.electron.fs.writeFileSync(\${selectedDirectory[0]}/invoices-total.json`, JSON.stringify(data))`
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API)

Is that what you’re looking for?

Notice that this API is not Sync and is promise based. You may meet to adjust you code to take advantage of this API